# Wait until event in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use ScheduledExecutorService to schedule a sequence of events that comprise a trial in an experiment. Each event happens after the previous event has completed (e.g. there is no concurrency). The timing of some events are controlled by the program (and seem to lend themselves to scheduleWithFixedDelay). The sequence of other events, however, is partially determined by user input, such as clicking a button. Here is an outline of the events in pseudo code:

```
present fixation cross
1 second delay
remove fixation cross
add stimulus
1 second delay
remove stimulus
for(question in questions){
  presentQuestion(question);
  wait until button click
  clearQuestion(question);
  1 second delay
}
```

I was able to implement the tasks up to the for loop using scheduleWithFixedDelay. I am stuck trying to incorporate the rest of the events. Here is what I have so far:

```
private void Schedule(){
    executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable task = () -> {
        try {
            if(trial > Ntrials){
                stopSession();
                executor.shutdown();
                return;
            }
            addCross();
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
            removeCross();
            addStimulus();  
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000);
            removeStimulus();

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("task interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("Shutdown");
        executor.shutdown();
    };
    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

Any examples or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the different steps dependent on previous ones being completed?

Comment: Yes. At least in the sense that they follow the outlined order and during the question presentation (the for loop) each question is presented individually after a button click and 1 second delay. Does that clarify everything?

Comment: Just to further clarify,  each step  depends on the previous step being complete. So everything is sequential and non-overlapping.  Sorry about that.

Comment: If so, I would say you're over designing it. The only thing you should be using the scheduler for, is the second delay.

Comment: Ok. I see. I'm fairly new to scheduling and am a little overwhelmed with the different methods available. Can you provide a minimum working example with fixed delays and event based delays (e.g. advancing to the next step upon button click?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code you're trying to run is sequential, the only thing you should be using the `ScheduledExecutor` for is the delay.

Think about it this way - the scheduler allows you to take a piece of code and run it some time in the future.

So what you really want is:

```
present fixation cross
in 1 second:
  remove fixation cross
  add stimulus
  in 1 second:
    remove stimulus
    ...
```

And so on.

To implement `in 1 second:`, you use the scheduler like this:

```
executor.schedule(callable, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Where `callable` is some instance of `Callable` that returns a result (you can also use the other variant that uses a `Runnable` if it doesn't return anything).

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand. It looks like you recommend calling the method for each event from executor.schedule, rather than from the one runnable, as I have done above. Do you have any recommendations for advancing to the next step based on an event, such as a button click?

Comment: Which mechanism are you using for presenting the questions / getting the answers?

Comment: Each question is presented as text with a JLabel. Below the JLabel I have a JSlider where the user inputs a judgment on a sliding scale. Once the JSlider value is chosen, the user submits the response by clicking a JButton located below the JSlider. The JButton has been added to an action listener.

Comment: Well, there's your answer, then. The action listener gets invoked on click. In the *onClick* code, you'll have to use the same executor and such. You can provide those as dependencies when creating the listener.

Comment: Thanks. The high level workflow make sense. I guess the crux of my issue has been the details of implementation. From what I gather, callable (as opposed to runnable) returns a result. But I don't know how to use that to stop executor.schedule from running from actionPerformed. Would I call future.cancel(true) from actionPerformed, where future is an instance of ScheduledFuture<?>  or something else?

Comment: Yes, that would cause the task to be cancelled. All this is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)).